# Invalid `Podfile` file: Unable to locate the executable `node`

Tags: cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm trying to run my App on IMB Cloud. Server run is OK. NPM Installed and Started. When POD Install from cd /ios it shows error:

denisbondar@MBP-Denis ios % pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unable to locate the executable `node`.

#  from /Users/denisbondar/Documents/kickapp/starter-kit/mobile-app/ios/Podfile:48
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #

> use_native_modules!
>    #  end
>    #  -------------------------------------------

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem
os: el capitan 10.11.6
cocoapods: 1.5.2
react native: 0.62
node: 8.9.0

Comment: I'm having the same too! :( did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

For me problem was that I have cocoa pods installed by `brew install cocoapods` and `brew install --cask cocoapods`.
So to fix I run

1. `brew remove cocoapods`
2. `brew remove --cask cocoapods`
3. `brew install cocoapods`

After that I have latest version of cocoapods and everything worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Issue. As I was trying to run a React Native App, and I needed some node module I have to run

```
brew install node
```

Comment: I had terrible time with react native project setup. I finally reinstalled my macOS then used this command after `sudo gem install cocoapods` and it eventually worked.

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same issue, after updating cocoa pods the installation passed:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: even after i updated 10 times, the issue still persist :(

Comment: @Michimcchicken hy are you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

```
brew remove cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your answer to add some explanation of how it works?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running into this issue on an M1 Mac, this is what fixed it for me:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

In your /ios directory:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that the commands I ran in order to fix my build have already been mentioned on this page, but I'll try to provide the order I ran them + some backstory.

For me the problem was that I've initally installed cocoapods using homebrew and I couldn't get it to update past version 1.5.2. Tried different approaches but `pod --version` still printed `1.5.2`.

Then I've tried installing cocoapods using gems with:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Even if it displayed that the installation of cocoapods 1.10.1 was successful, the command line from terminal still pointed to the homebrew version of cocoapods, and `pod --version` still printed out `1.5.2`. So I had to remove it, by calling:

```
brew remove cocoapods
```

After that the command line pointed to the gems version of cocoapods (`1.10.1`). And the build was successful.

BEWARE I AM MAC OS NOOBIE SO PROCEED WITH CAUSION FOR THE NEXT PART

Also, my friend tried to follow the exact same steps and his build still failed until he tried installing:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

then after the installation he ran:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Again, I am a MAC OS noobie, so I don't understand very well yet what's the deal with this ffi. It just helped my friend getting his build done, so I thought it might also help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if there is no space in the folder path, where the project is located. Spaces in the folder name can give this issue.